# foreach prints both results

Tags: php, foreach, codeigniter-3

```
<?php 
    foreach ($myassignment->result() as $e){
        $courseId=$e->courseId;
        $getassign=$this->Usermodel->getmysubassignment($courseId);     

        if($getassign->num_rows()==''){
            print_r('no rows');
        } else {
            print_r('some rows');
        }                           
    }
?>
```

In the above code $myassignment contains 2 courseId's. In that first courseId doesn't return anything from DB using `$getassign=$this->Usermodel->getmysubassignment($courseId);` and second one return something. But it prints both `no rows` and `some rows` but I need only `some rows`. What to do?

Comment: Use `if($getassign->num_rows() > 0){ print_r('some rows');}`

Comment: this time also printing both

Comment: Don't use else condition just use it as my above comment

Comment: but i need to show an error messages also when there is no rows

Comment: When you want to show error message? I mean at what condition??

Comment: If there is no rows print that `no rows` mesaage. if rows are there prints `some rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't react to a future iteration of the loop. Just move your output outside the loop:

```
$resultscount = 0;
foreach ($myassignment->result() as $e)
 {
  ...
  $resultscount += $getassign->num_rows();
 }
if ($resultscount > 0) // good catch, Saty. Thanks!
 {
  print_r('some rows');
  // you can now also use the number of rows in output:
  print_r($resultscount . ' row' . ($resultscount > 1 ? 's' : ''));
 }
else
  print_r('no rows');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `flag` for that

```
$flag = FALSE;// set if false
    foreach ($myassignment->result() as $e) {
        $courseId = $e->courseId;
        $getassign = $this->Usermodel->getmysubassignment($courseId);

        if ($getassign->num_rows() > 0) {
            $flag = TRUE;// if row then set it true
        }
    }// end of foreach loop
    if ($flag) {
        print_r('some rows');
    } else {
        print_r('no rows');
    }
```